# C# ignores trailing space in value when using DataTable's Select command

Tags: c#, linq, select, datatable

When I try to access a value with a space at the end from a `DataTable`, C# fails to recognize it. To clarify, the `value` variable in: `Select(columnName + " = '" + value + "'")[0][newColumnName].ToString();` must not have a trailing space, or C# will produce inaccurate results.

Thing is, I have a LINQ equivalent which works okay, but I'm not sure how to create an equivalent 'set' function.

So an answer would either be a way to fix this apparent bug in C#, or help write an equivalent LINQ `set()` function to my LINQ `get()` (i.e. without using `Select()` ). Both solutions would be even better.

Here's the fully working code you can use to show what I have so far, and reproduce the bug. The output I get is: green, red, red, also-red ....when it should be: green, red, also-red, also-red

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace datatable_trailing_space_bug
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SuperDataTable table = new SuperDataTable();

            /////////////////////////////
            table.Columns.Add("fruitName", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("colour", typeof(string));

            //////////////  name, type, colour, length
            table.Rows.Add("apple", "green");
            table.Rows.Add("banana", "yellow");
            table.Rows.Add("strawberry", "red");
            table.Rows.Add("strawberry ", "also-red");

            Console.WriteLine(table._get_FAILS_ON_TRAILING_SPACE("fruitName", "apple", "colour"));          // This works - "green"
            Console.WriteLine(table._get_FAILS_ON_TRAILING_SPACE("fruitName", "strawberry", "colour"));     // This works - "red"
            Console.WriteLine(table._get_FAILS_ON_TRAILING_SPACE("fruitName", "strawberry ", "colour"));    // This fails due to trailing space - "red" (should be "also-red")
            Console.WriteLine(table._get_WORKS("fruitName", "strawberry ", "colour"));                      // This works - "also-red"


            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }


    public class SuperDataTable : DataTable
    {
        public SuperDataTable()
        {
        }
        public string _get_FAILS_ON_TRAILING_SPACE(string columnName, string value, string newColumnName)       {
            value = value.Replace("'", "''");
            return Select(columnName + " = '" + value + "'")[0][newColumnName].ToString();
        }
        public void _set_FAILS_ON_TRAILING_SPACE(string columnName, string value, string newColumnName, string newValue) {
            value = value.Replace("'", "''");
            Select(columnName + "='" + value + "'")[0][newColumnName] = newValue;
        }

        public string _get_WORKS(string columnName, string value, string newColumnName) {
            string output = this.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(s => s.Field<string>(columnName).Equals(value))
                .Select(s => s.Field<string>(newColumnName)).FirstOrDefault();
            return output;
        }
        public void _set_WORKS(string columnName, string value, string newColumnName, string newValue) {
            // Enter working code here please.
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the working Linq option, using the [SetField(DataRow, String, T) extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353039.aspx):

```
    public void _set_WORKS(string columnName, string value, string newColumnName, string newValue) {
         var output = this.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(s => s.Field<string>(columnName).Equals(value))
            .FirstOrDefault();
        output.SetField<string>(newColumnName, newValue);
    }
```

Comment: Simple when you know how - thanks! Bounty coming your way as promised. If anyone wants to provide a fix for the 'other way' of doing it, that would still be interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, this has become a feature.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/700010/datatable-select-trailing-blanks-in-search-string

> After carefully analizing it, we concluded that if we fix this problem, we may potentially break exisiting applications that relies on this issue. Because of that, we are closing this issue as Won't Fix.

Comment: That's what I get too. The second last being "red" is the bug. It should be: green, red, also-red, also-red. I've edited the question to clarify this further. Btw, I think this should have been a comment below my question, rather than an answer in itself.

Comment: @DanW, you might want to post simpler working examples in the future.

I also think this should have been a comment, but I'm not reputable enough to comment other than my own responses. And if I hadn't done that you wouldn't have got no one's attention. :(

I've edited the response to be a proper response.

By the way, this is not a C# issue. It's a .NET BCL (Base Class Library) issue related to DataTables. You might want to remove the C# and LINQ tags to broaden the scope of the question and benefit from and/or help others.

Comment: Thank you. That's disappointing to hear that Microsoft would practically ignore something as fundamental as this. I'll still hold out for a LINQ-style answer or some other workaround. I don't think there'll be any harm in keeping the tags as I think MORE, not less will see it if they are watching out for those particular tags.

Comment: Totally agree. A workaround should be provided either as a global setting or as some kind of switch.

For select you're covered with LINQ. But I wonder how it is for DataViews.